# Trouble setting UISwitch in FlipsideViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, properties, uiviewcontroller, uicontrol

I have an iPhone utility app from the standard template, so I have `MainViewController` and `FlipsideViewController` that gets initialized and called `controller.`  In `controller's` xib I have a `UISwitch` called `pathSwitch` and a `UISegmentedControl` called `locationSelector` that are outlets (and hooked up!)  When I call the `showInfo:(id)sender` method, I do the following:

[EDIT] Adding the interface of the `controller...`
[EDIT 2] Updated interface to show added properties

```
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender {    
    ALog(@"method begin...");
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
    DLog(@">sun path visible = %@, setting flip side controller switch", sunPathIsVisible ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    // deleted -> [controller.pathSwitch setOn:sunPathIsVisible];
    controller.sunPathIsVisible = sunPathIsVisible; // added this
    DLog(@">location mode is %d, setting flip side controller segment index to %d - 1 = %d", locationMode, locationMode, locationMode - 1);
    // deleted -> controller.locationSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = locationMode - 1;
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.locationMode = locationMode; // added this
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

---

```
@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController {
    id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
    int locationMode; // added this
    UISegmentedControl *locationSelector;
    BOOL sunPathIsVisible;
    UISwitch *pathSwitch;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property int locationMode; // added this
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *locationSelector;
@property BOOL sunPathIsVisible; // added this
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *pathSwitch;;

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;

@end

// There's also the `protocol` stuff, but I left that out here...
```

---

The problem is that the controls do not accept their values and always show segment 0 and OFF.  If I set their properties in `controller's` `viewWillAppear` method, they do show the correct setting.

Is `controller` not fully loaded when I do this or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably right. The cleanest way would be to add some properties to the `FlipsideViewController`, and set those. Then let `viewWillAppear` set the actual switches using these properties.

This will also put the UI layout issues of `FlipsideViewController` where they belong, namely in `FlipsideViewController` and not in any other controller that may ever use it. (i.e. if you ever decide to not use a switch but some kind of button, you can change `FlipsideViewController` without having to look at other code)

**edit**

Some clarification. Try to add properties to `FlipsideViewController` with these lines at the relevant places:

```
BOOL switchState;
NSInteger locationMode;

@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL switchState;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger locationMode;

@synthesize switchState;
@synthesize locationMode;
```

Then, in your current `-(IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender` you could say:

```
FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc]
                                         initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
controller.switchState = sunPathIsVisible;
controller.locationMode = locationMode;
controller.delegate = self;
// etc etc
```

Then, in `FlipsideViewController`, in `viewDidLoad`, put the actual handling of the switch value:

```
[self.pathSwitch setOn:self.sunPathIsVisible];
[self.locationSelector setSelectedSegmentIndex:self.locationMode];
```

This will a) solve your problem and b) separate your concerns regarding the user interface. If you would decide to change the layout of `FlipsideViewController`, there is no need to change any code other than that of `FlipsideViewController`.

There are other ways of achieving this, e.g. by letting your `viewDidLoad` fetch the value from its delegate, which would look like:

```
[self.pathSwitch setOn:[delegate pathSwitch]];
```

Which may be better, depending on your situation. Generally speaking I would always prefer this last approach, since it prevents synchronisation issues between your different view controllers.

Comment: Thanks - not sure what you mean though... I declare the `UISwitch` and `UISegmentedControl` as properties (and IBOutlets).  I'll add the interface of `controller`...

Comment: The first approach works - thanks.  I still don't understand why, if I have made the switch and segmented control properties, I can't set them directly once the view controller has been instantiated.  Seems like a convoluted way of doing things.  I liked the second method better, but got lots of errors about `-locationMode getter not defined in <id>delegate` or some such (can't recall exactly)

Comment: It's because you apparently don't tell the compiler what kind of object `delegate` points to. The quick fix is to change it from `id` to `RootViewController` (I guess?), but the proper way would be to define your own protocol, and declare the delegate as `id<MyVeryOwnProtocol> delegate;`. But for now just try to silence the compiler, once that's done you can look for further improvements.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but shouldn't this be

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *locationSelector;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *pathSwitch;
```

instead of

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *locationSelector;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UISwitch *pathSwitch;;
```

Comment: Good catch - I copied the `@property...` stuff from the delegate property declaration, which from the template is `assign.`  Fixed in question. +1